# Mecanum simulation possible using directional friction?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've been following with interest the evolving story for how to simulate mecanum wheels in Gazebo— planar move, fake casters, etc.

However, it was recently pointed out to me that it may be possible to do a pretty accurate simulation of a mecanum wheel using a single cylinder with directional friction on the circumference. Is this a realistic possibility? Is there a good example of this somewhere to experiment with? The idea of using a pure-SDF solution without needing a custom plugin for this robot is extremely appealing, if it's possible.

Thanks for any pointers or thoughts.

---

**Edit:** These are the mecanum wheels in my project: http://www.andymark.com/product-p/am-0137.htm

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8737/mecanum-simulation-possible-using-directional-friction?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In my first answer, I didn't understand your proposal exactly. Now I see that you're suggesting to model the entire wheel as a single cylinder and set directional friction properties to simulate the mecanum wheel rollers.

ODE supports two friction coefficients (`mu` and `mu2` in sdformat in [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=friction&cat=physics)) with a pyramid friction model. The friction directions corresponding to each coefficient are computed to be orthogonal to each other and the contact normal unit vector. If the [fdir1 parameter](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=collision#ode_fdir1) is not set, then the first friction direction is computed from the component of the global X axis that is orthogonal to the unit normal. The second friction direction is then computed to be mutually orthogonal with a vector cross product. In the case where objects are contacting a ground plane normal to the Z axis, then the X and Y axes are the first and second friction directions respectively.

If the [fdir1 parameter](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=collision#ode_fdir1) is set to a non-zero vector, then that vector is interpreted as the desired first friction direction in the body-fixed Link frame of the object. This makes it challenging to model mecanum wheels, since the link frame will be rotating as the wheel spins. It would be better to define the friction direction relative to the wheel carrier (spindle). This would require a modification to gazebo, but it sounds like it would be useful.

Did that make sense?

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on 2015-05-17**:
Yes, and that was my primary concern— that it would be impossible to maintain the orientation of the friction within a moving contact patch. Unfortunately, this platform's simulator needs to work with ROS Jade's Gazebo for sure, and probably Indigo's too, so that pretty much rules out any changes to the core (though such changes could be of benefit to future users).

How possible would it be to get this behaviour from a plugin, in your estimate?